# Connect two computers without crossover cable

Tags: ethernet, cat5e

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [direct ethernet connection between two wirelessly connected Windows 7 laptops](https://superuser.com/questions/299901/direct-ethernet-connection-between-two-wirelessly-connected-windows-7-laptops)

Is is possible to connect two computers without a crossover Cat 5e cable?

Comment: see if [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/15367/how-do-i-wire-a-crossover-cable-to-connect-two-devices-together/15373#15373) or [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/5179/should-i-use-a-network-hub-or-network-switch/5192#5192) answers your question...

Answer (score 7):

Some computers have autosensing capability and would switch the orientation themselves. 
But most computers wont do it, sorry.

Comment: this is called [Auto-MDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX).

Comment: Lots of useful info in quack's link - i.e. its only in the Gigabit standard and if you connect 2 together you will get a switching loop. You may want to expand your answer.

Comment: if it is HP only tech probably most ethernet cards do not have it. thanks for the link.

Comment: If both computers are reasonable modern Macs (last three years or so) this will work out of the box with a normal cable.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a modern computer (w/Gigabit), then it will work just fine.  Otherwise, probably not.  Older switches/hubs sometimes had autodetect for cable type, but NICs typically did not (I can't think of any that did right now).

Comment: as i tried out between gigabit and megabit ethernet machines **non** crossover cable just works fine! wow, how come no one explicitly told this?!

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you are connecting two computers from straight cat 5 and one computer must have Linux OS e.g. Ubuntu.

I've tried this before and it was successful

- Windows to Windows will not work

I tried

- Ubuntu to Windows Vista and it was successful!

not on any other Linux or Windows.