# Setup an inside network using a switch while connected to a wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, switch

I've recently moved into my dorm at my new school.  Everything is done via wifi but I would like to still have my own private network inside of my dorm (I have several computers).  I went out and bought a Switch which I quickly attached to each of my comptuers.

I've assigned each computer a unique address and a subnet address.  I want to be able to use things such as Synergy across all of my computers but to this point, I have yet to succeed.

Everything seems to want to go through the wireless network instead of my local network.  The network is also seen as unidentified which means it forces it to be a public network (not what I want - I want it to be a home network so I can share directories and stuff...)  I have set the two IP's to be different (*192.168.0.1* and *192.168.0.2*).

Do any of you know how I can set this all up?

Comment: So each PC has a wireless NIC (using DHCP?) and a wired NIC (using static IP address?)?.  *"I've assigned each computer a unique address and a subnet address"* - Please provide a few examples.

Comment: @sawdust :: None of them are Linux.  The Wireless assigned everything like a normal one would (using DHCP).  However, the switch doesn't do any assigning so I assigned them the static IPs on their adapters (not the wireless adapter).  I have two examples of the IPs that I assigned :: *192.168.0.1* and *192.168.0.1*

Comment: By "examples", please provide the IP addresses assigned to each interface on one or two PCs. That is, do you really have two distinct subnets?  It's impossible to diagnose a network problem if all you do is generalize about how you have configured eveything.  You need to paint a clear, concise picture with details.

Comment: @Sawdust :: Does this help?  Sorry, I'm busy setting up other things so it's difficult switching back and forth:  http://i49.tinypic.com/28vya1s.png

Comment: Okay. Now what protocols have been assigned to the wired interface?  From the "... Connection Status" popup, select Activity "Properties".  You definitely need IPv4, you don't need IPv6, apparently you want the "client for Microsoft networks".

Comment: @sawdust :: *Client for Microsoft Networks* is enabled as well as *IPv4*.  I currently have *IPv6* disabled for it.

Comment: So you said that `ping 192.168.0.2` would go over the wireless?  Try also `arping` besides `ping`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar to this with [two systems](https://superuser.com/questions/299901/direct-ethernet-connection-between-two-wirelessly-connected-windows-7-laptops) and there's no reason it should not work- From what i can tell the mistake you're making is using the same subnet on both networks - they're different enough, but there's a chance that your school DHCP server is using the rest of the 192.168.x.x subnet.

You might want to try using the 10.x.x.x subnet instead. Where there's an option you might also be able to bind specific applications to specific interfaces - for synergy try the [-a option on the server](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/running.html) to set the server to listen to a specific ip address.

Comment: I've made updates to my question to reflect the changes you suggested.