# How can I use a crossover cable with Synergy or ShareMouse?

Tags: wireless-networking, synergy, crossover

I have a Laptop with a mouse and keyboard, and a mac with mouse and keyboard and sucky internet connection on the mac. They both have wireless, and I have a crossover cable to connect them. How can I force Synergy/ShareMouse traffic to only go over the crossover cable to remove the sucky latency between the two?

Comment: You don't need a crossover cable if either system (or both!) have gigabit ethernet. How are the laptop and mac set up? Static IPs?

Comment: Ya, they have static ip addresses, but I'm trying to connect through crossover, and not wireless.

Answer (score 0):

[This is covered on synergy's support Q&A site](http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/questions/165/force-synergy-to-use-lan-rather-than-wireless)

In detail, you want to set up the laptop and mac to use a different IP address range - in your shoes I'd go with a simple static IP address on either side, then tell the systems to connect using those IP addresses, rather than the hostnames.

Comment: But won't that still send all the information over wireless? I don't have ethernet access from either of my machines, so my only options are to be stuck with sucky wireless or crossover.

Comment: not if you tell it to *specifically* use the ip address. You'd also (rather obviously) use addresses from a different range from the wireless connection

Comment: How do I do that exactly?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/299901/direct-ethernet-connection-between-two-wirelessly-connected-windows-7-laptops/299907#299907 is what I did with windows systems. You'll need to adjust one side for your mac

Comment: My Mac keeps saying "connection refused" in Synergy after I followed those guides.