# Transfer files over hardwired LAN for speed; computers are also WiFi connected

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-8, wireless-networking

I am a web developer. I don’t have much knowledge in networking.

- I have to transfer almost 200 GB files from a Ubuntu 14.04 laptop to a Windows 8 laptop.
- They are connected to the Internet through a WiFi router with gateway 192.168.0.1.

I sent files using [FireFTP](http://fireftp.net)  but the transfer was extremely slow. For 8 GB it took almost 5 hours.

Today, I bought a LAN cable with 8P8C modular connectors. When I connected it to both the laptops, it showed limited access. On the Windows laptop, it shows “Unidentified Network”, and on the Ubuntu laptop, “Disconnected Ethernet” network.

My issue is:

- I don’t want to stop my work, which requires a WiFi Internet connection.
- File transfer should also happen using LAN cable.

So the questions are

- Is it really possible?
- If so, what Internet configuration needs to be changed in both the Windows 8 and Ubuntu laptops?
- If it is not possible, can I transfer files faster using the WiFi connection. FYI, I have a [D-Link N300 WiFi router](http://us.dlink.com/products/connect/wireless-n300-router/). I could have a wrong configuration since file transfer is slower. If so, how can I debug that?

Comment: If you decided to use LAN, make sure that the cable is cross wired. Only with a cross wired LAN cable you can make point to pint connection. Also check the link below on how to configure http://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-setup-a-lan-between-ubuntu-and-windows

Comment: Nope. You don't

Comment: @vembutech What’s a cross wired cable? I’ve used regular ethernet cables between two computers for a few years and don’t know what you’re talking about.

Comment: You need crossover cables for ethernet adaptors without auto mdx. The gig-e base T specs mandated mdx as a compulsory feature IIRC, so they're obsolete.

Comment: If you check the LAN cable, you can find the same colour patterns in both ends of the modular connectors. It is called straight cable. Cross over cable is similar LAN cable where one end of the cable has reversed colour patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this between [windows connected system](https://superuser.com/a/299907/10165), and the fundamentals are the same.

Set up *static* ip addresses on a different range (I'd pick a different 'class' of RFC1918 ranges to be safe) on both systems (depending on your WM and OS, there might be a GUI for this), and *do not set a default gateway*. Not setting a default gateway essentially tells your system not to use that interface for internet access.

If *either* device is gigabit ethernet, a straight cable will work. If *both* devices are fast Ethernet or worse you need a crossover cable.

Then just use the static ip for your file transfer.

Comment: Really thank you for the answers! I found my cable was not a crossover, I could not follow your answers. I had to do this thing only once for now. So I thought, buying another cable would not be feasible for me.
Instead I stopped all my work and connected two laptops with straight LAN cable from the suggestion given by @vembutech. It took almost 1-1/2 hour. Now, I'm done with it. From my workaround it seems I should consider JourneymanGeek's answer. I think, I will need it for sure.

Comment: Actually vembutech suggested crossovers. Multiple people mentioned it isn't needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 doesn't exactly agree with most ad-hoc or cable to cable connections unless you have a crossover cable. I would recommend purchasing a crossover cable and going from there. As to the network fixes, at least for the windows 8 laptop:

http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/30664-5-ways-to-fix-slow-80211n-speed

If this doesn't help, try a large flash drive, or compressing the files using WinRAR or 7Zip.

Or, you know, an external hard drive. Or a USB connector, just take out the hard drive of one device and connect it to the other.

If it HAS to be over network, I feel for you. 13.7 GB from Win7 Regal Business Edition to an 8.1 laptop using a router.

Last resort, let it run overnight. Patience pays.

Comment: Crossover cables are obsolete with gig-e networking

Comment: @AlexSwenson:- Thanks for the answer. compressing 200 GB data either separately or collectively would not be feasible. Hard-drive or USB connector was my last option.