# Prioritize LAN cable to access network (shared) drives over Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, lan, home-networking

##### Situation

I've two PC connected with LAN cable *(**without** internet access)* to each other. They also are on the same Wi-Fi network *(**with** internet access)*.

##### Current behavior

- When I use Internet on browser -> It uses Wi-Fi connection.
- When I access Network *(shared)* drives from my other PC -> It **again** uses Wi-Fi connection.

##### What I want to achieve

- When I use Internet on browser -> It uses Wi-Fi connection.
- When I access Network *(shared)* drives from my other PC -> **It should prioritize LAN cable to access the files**

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use separate vLANs on the router, putting two LAN ports on the router on a separate vLAN, or separate the bonding between the WiFi and LAN ports on the router. For anyone to write an answer. more detail is required, such as the OS being used and the router being used.

Comment: What OS do they run?

Comment: Also how are you connecting between the two machines? the way the machines are set up is important, I need things  like IPs

Comment: Two PC are connected via LAN cable **to each other** and not to the router.

Answer (score 1):

I've vaguely got a similar setup or used one in the past. It needs a little bit of tweaking but there's a few elements here

1. Treat the wifi and wired networks as two *different* subnets, say 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x
2. You need to set up a static IP on either side on the wired interfaces - this is a setup I used [in the past](https://superuser.com/questions/299901/direct-ethernet-connection-between-two-wirelessly-connected-windows-7-laptops/299907#299907)
3. test the routes for the wired interfaces to ensure you're going the right way - use the IPs not the hostnames
4. USE THE IPS, not hostnames to connect to the fileshares.

This *should* work

Comment: Quick note - in my example on the other post, I had to set a default gateway on one end. To this day I have no idea why that's needed.